# Sustaining parameter values in multi threads that are created dynamically? (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

I can't say i fully understood the concept of threads even i read so many articles over it, i'm a bit thick and what i want is thread safe parameters. I'm sending string arguments to a thread that i'm using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem to start but i'm using the same thread just after it again with another arguments.

What i want from it to be able to process different threads with different arguments but its not stable probably because i'm changing the parameter string just after calling the first thread. My instincts tell me to use Lock but don't know how to and where..

Oh btw the output of this code is usually 3 threads working with the latest parameter (which is configurations for 200p)

The code i use to call my thread is this;

```
    processThread pt = new processThread();
    pt.fileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "bin\\ffmpeg.exe";
    pt.filePath = Path.Combine(Vci.Core.Sandbox.UploaderControlSandboxPath, fileGuid);
    pt.vidPathHigh = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "videos\\480p\\" + fileGuid + ".wmv";
    pt.vidPathMid = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "videos\\360p\\" + fileGuid + ".wmv";
    pt.vidPathLow = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "videos\\200p\\" + fileGuid + ".wmv";
    if (height >= 480) 
    {
        newHeight = (int)Math.Floor(480 * aspectRatio);
        initArgs = "-i " + pt.filePath + " -vcodec wmv2 -qscale 2 -s " + newHeight + "x480 -acodec wmav2 -ar 44100 -ab 128k -y \"" + pt.vidPathHigh + "\"";
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => pt.callExecute(initArgs));
        newHeight = (int)Math.Floor(360 * aspectRatio);
        initArgs = "-i " + pt.filePath + " -vcodec wmv2 -qscale 4 -s " + newHeight + "x360 -acodec wmav2 -ar 44100 -ab 128k -y \"" + pt.vidPathMid + "\"";
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => pt.callExecute(initArgs));
        newHeight = (int)Math.Floor(200 * aspectRatio);
        initArgs = "-i " + pt.filePath + " -vcodec wmv2 -qscale 6 -s " + newHeight + "x200 -acodec wmav2 -ar 44100 -ab 128k -y \"" + pt.vidPathLow + "\"";
    }
```

And code to my thread Class is this;

```
    public class processThread
    {
    public string filePath { get; set; }
    public string fileName { get; set; }
    public string vidPathHigh { get; set; }
    public string vidPathMid { get; set; }
    public string vidPathLow { get; set; }
    public void callExecute(Object o)
    {
        try
        {
            executeProcess(fileName, o as string);
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException abortException)
        {
            // do something
        }
    }

    private void executeProcess(string fileName, string arguments)
    {
        Process myProcess = new Process();
        myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = fileName;
        myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
        myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
        myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
        try
        {
            myProcess.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
        myProcess.WaitForExit();
        myProcess.Close();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance any help is appreciated!

Comment: Edit: sorry, didnt read the code properly

Comment: I may be the one missing something. You may be right, i thought ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem was doing the same thing as myThread.start(executeProcess) so instead of this i started using ThreadPool, and got the same thing, what i want actually, execution process of an HD video (which takes too long) continues but the user can do whatever he wants. But if ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem() starts a process and can't do what i want i'm open to other solutions too. Thank you!

Comment: When you create a new Process, your application does'nt wait for this process to end, so the use of threading here is unnecessary

Comment: Yes i know but, i can't create another process at the same time either before its done, or i can't get the return from my webservice anyhow i need this for my architecture. I wish i could never sail into the seas that i know nothing of but..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are "capturing" `initargs` via the use of the lambda expression.

You shouldn't be reusing `initargs` in this way. Your code will be more readable and easier to maintain, and you will avoid this problem.

So, first, use two different instances of `initargs`:

```
string initArgsWithScaleTwo = // 
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => pt.callExecute(initArgsWithScaleTwo));
string initArgsWithScaleFour = //
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(o => pt.callExecute(initArgsWithScaleFour));
```

Second, there's a lot of needless repetition when you assign to `initArgs`. That's not fun to maintain. This should get you started on a clearer version:

```
private string GetInitArgs(
    string filePath,
    int scale,
    int newHeight,
    string vidPathHigh,
    int scanLines
) {
    return "-i " + filePath + String.Format(" -vcodec wmv2 -qscale {0} -s ", scale) + newHeight + String.Format("x{0} -acodec wmav2 -ar 44100 -ab 128k -y \"" + pt.vidPathHigh + "\"", scanLines);
}
```

You can do more and use `String.Format` to really clean the whole thing up.

Then you can say

```
string initArgsWithScaleTwoAnd480ScanLines = 
    GetInitArgs(
       pt.filePath,
       2,
       (int)Math.Floor(480 * aspectRatio,
       pt.vidPathHigh,
       480
    );
```

All that said, I don't understand why you are using threads at all if the threads are merely starting new processes. Just start the processes directly, and wait for them all to finish.

Comment: Thank you! It worked, i should've looked back to my lessons in school pass by value pass by reference.... And thanks for the warning i lost my self when i'm trying to debug this so i just wrote the worst code i could ever.. I will definitely fix this! Cheers!

Comment: @umutto: To be very clear: the issue here is not, Not, NOT pass by reference. You aren't passing parameters by reference. The issue is that you had used `initArgs` in a lambda expression. Therefore, it was "captured." This means the compiler created a class for you, lifted `initArgs` as a field to that class. Then, it created an instance of that class for you. And that's the key, it only created one instance and every invocation to queue a new thread was seeing the same instance. So, your threads were all sharing the same instance of this compiler generated class. Clear?

Comment: Yes sir, thanks again for removing the clouds about lambda expression, this info actually helped me more now that i can edit wisely. Cheers.

Comment: @umutto: One more thing. You said "i lost my self when i'm trying to debug this so i just wrote the worst code i could ever." Your future self will thank you if you just always write code correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, I am not sure if I understand what you are asking. `Process.Start` normally does not block current thread, so you can start as many new processes as your system can swallow from single thread of your application...

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer, what i want is to start my process with different arguments. But i'm not able to since i'm changing the arguments right after i call my thread, the executeProcess() in all my threads usually gets the 3rd threads arguments. So at the and i get 3 threads trying to process my video to 200p. But i want 3 threads processing for 480p 360p and 200p as i call in first code. Thank youu!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where `initArgs` is defined, so changing that and calling threads which use it could lead to some problems.

But I'd recommend you look at Joseph Albahari's [free e-book](http://www.albahari.com/threading/) on Threading.  It's an excellent resource and provides some good suggestions on how to design your code for various threading scenarios.  In your case, you may want to consider the [Wait and Pulse](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Signaling_with_Wait_and_Pulse) pattern.

Comment: Thank you, seems like a great source definitely will check it out!